# How to use a HubTile for the Application Tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to add some animation to my main application tile when it is pinned to the start screen, and was wondering how this is possible. I've thought about creating a HubTile in my CreateApplicationTile() method, but I do not know if this is possible or how this would be accomplished? Any suggestions?

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public void CreateApplicationTile()
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("/Background.png", UriKind.Relative);

        HubTile tile = new HubTile
        {
            Title = "ShareSky",
            Source = bitmap

        };

        var appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

        if (appTile != null)
        {
            var standardTile = new StandardTileData
            {
                //Title = "ShareSky",
                ////BackgroundImage = new Uri("Images/SecondaryTileFrontIcon.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                ////Count = 13, // any number can go here, leaving this null shows NO number
                //BackTitle = "ShareSky",
                ////BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Images/ApplicationTileIcon.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                //BackContent = "Click Me!"                    
            };

            appTile.Update(standardTile);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to do for Windows Phone 7.5. This is something planned for Windows Phone 8

Comment: Thanks for the info Shawn, should be something worth looking forward to!

Comment: I agree! Looking forward to the new possibilities with Windows Phone 8. Hopefully as easy as [tile updates in WinRT](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2012/08/15/Adding-multiple-lines-of-text-to-your-Win8-tile-update.aspx)