# Own layout for LiveTiles

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, layout, live-tile

I'd like to make some fancy live tiles. But I am not quite happy with the default options for it. Is there a way in C#/XAML or any site, that shows how to put an own design for a live tile?

Comment: what are you looking to change? Please also refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962949/how-to-use-a-hubtile-for-the-application-tile/11964068#11964068) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963139/how-to-correctly-pin-a-hubtile-to-the-start-screen/11964062#11964062)

Comment: Primarily the font sizes. Is there any way to change these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default font size of the [Tile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) cannot be changed. You can only change the text. What you can do is create an image that has text on it and set that to the [BackgroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata.backgroundimage%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) or the [BackBackgroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata.backbackgroundimage%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). You can create an image by using the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).